# How can I determine the types of generic parameters of a class that is itself generic?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I need to determine the type of a generic parameter in a situation where the type in question can have its own generic types. Below is code that worked until this nesting of generics came up.

```
inline fun <reified T : Units> Units?.zero(): Measure<T> {
    return when (T::class) {
        Energy::class -> 0.0 * (joules as T)
        Frequency::class -> 0.0 * (hertz as T)
        Time::class -> 0.0 * (seconds as T)
        Spin::class -> 0.0 * (rpm as T)
        Volume::class -> 0.0 * (liters as T)
        Temperature::class -> 0.0 * (celsius as T)
        UnitsRatio<Energy, Time>::class -> 0.0 * (watts as T) // this does not work
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get this generic type information about `UnitsRatio`?

**Background**

I'm using [Measured](https://github.com/nacular/measured), a library to help with managing physical measurement units. Basically, my function is supposed to be a way to obtain a measure with a value of 0 without knowing the exact measurement unit explicitly, as it should be inferred by the compiler. This would enable me to get a sum of measurement values from a collection.

```
val SUnits: Units? = null
inline fun <T, reified U : Units> Collection<T>.sumOf(selector: (T) -> Measure<U>): Measure<U> {
    var sum: Measure<U> = SUnits.zero()
    for (element in this) {
        sum += selector(element)
    }
    return sum
}
```

This makes the usage clean and similar to existing `sumOf` variants. For example:

```
val totalVolume = bodies.sumOf { it.volume }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to compare against the *types*, rather than the *classes* of `T` and the unit types.

```
inline fun <reified T : Units> Units?.zero(): Measure<T> {
    return when (typeOf<T>()) {
        typeOf<Energy>() -> 0.0 * (joules as T)
        typeOf<Frequency>() -> 0.0 * (hertz as T)
        typeOf<Time>() -> 0.0 * (seconds as T)
        typeOf<Spin>() -> 0.0 * (rpm as T)
        typeOf<Volume>() -> 0.0 * (liters as T)
        typeOf<Temperature>() -> 0.0 * (celsius as T)
        typeOf<UnitsRatio<Energy, Time>>() -> 0.0 * (watts as T)
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

Note that this requires `kotlin.reflect`. There might be a better solution specific to the *Measured* library that you are using, which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that. I tried it and it works in some situations, but not when one of those inner types is generic. `typeOf<T>()` gives the generic type name and not the one it actually is at runtime. For example, `UnitsRatio<U, Time>` instead of `UnitsRatio<Energy, Time>`. Can I get around that somehow?

Comment: @Altline It should work if `U` is also reified. But if `U` is not reified, then you can't get around that, because you literally don't know what `U` is at runtime.

Comment: @Altline I reread your comment and found that your wording is a little ambiguous. In case I have misunderstood you, I think it is best to post a new question so that you can clarify by showing a [mcve] of this scenario.

Comment: I posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74837600/6640693) detailing what I mean.