# Generic type can't get resolved. How can I pass down its type information?

Tags: kotlin, generics

Let's say you have this class.

```
class Conduit<U : Units>(
    val flowRate: Measure<UnitsRatio<U, Time>>,
    val inputs: List<Conduit<U>> = emptyList()
) {
    fun test(): Measure<UnitsRatio<U, Time>> {
        return inputs.sumOf { it.flowRate }
    }
}
```

It models a conduit for transferring different physical values depending on `U`. If you wanted to sum up the total flow rate of all the inputs, it seems reasonable to have a call like the one in the `test()` function.

This is how I implemented the `sumOf` function.

```
val SUnits: Units? = null
inline fun <T, reified U : Units> Collection<T>.sumOf(selector: (T) -> Measure<U>): Measure<U> {
    var sum: Measure<U> = SUnits.zero()
    for (element in this) {
        sum += selector(element)
    }
    return sum
}
```

The problematic part starts here, where we need to get the zero starting value for our sum. Because the measurement unit is generic, the actual type needs to be checked in order to assign the correct unit. That is the purpose of the `zero()` function defined below.

```
inline fun <reified U : Units> Units?.zero(): Measure<U> {
    return when (typeOf<U>()) {
        typeOf<Energy>() -> 0.0 * (joules as U)
        typeOf<Volume>() -> 0.0 * (liters as U)
        typeOf<Time>() -> 0.0 * (seconds as U)
        typeOf<UnitsRatio<Energy, Time>>() -> 0.0 * (watts as U)
        typeOf<UnitsRatio<Volume, Time>>() -> 0.0 * ((liters / seconds) as U)
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

It checks the type of `U` and assigns the appropriate unit for it. However, when I test the following code, the type doesn't get recognized and my RuntimeException gets thrown.

```
Conduit(
    maxFlowRate = 1 * watts, // type: Measure<UnitsRatio<Energy, Time>>
    inputs = listOf(
        Conduit(maxFlowRate = 1 * watts),
        Conduit(maxFlowRate = 1 * watts)
    )
).test().also { println(it) }
```

I beleive this is due to type erasure which I have a hard time grasping. Whatever the case, I'm hoping there is a way to pass along that information so that the sum accumulator can be initialized.

---

The library used in this example is [Measured](https://github.com/nacular/measured).

Answer (score 2):

Why is your `zero()` function an extension on a Units object, but doesn't use the receiver for anything? If your goal was to use the receiver as the same type as the Measure, your function could simply be:

```
fun <U: Units> U.zero(): Measure<U> = Measure(0.0, this)
```

No reification or type-checking necessary for that.

But I guess the reason you need runtime checking is to be able to produce a 0.0 value based only on a generic type, not from an instance of Units. So remove the receiver from your function:

```
inline fun <reified U : Units> zero(): Measure<U> {
    return when (typeOf<U>()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Your `sumOf` function doesn't make sense because it has a `U` Units type, but it tries to use whatever is stored in the `SUnits` property, which might not be a match for `U` as requested by the function caller. I think it should probably look like the following.

```
inline fun <T, reified U : Units> Iterable<T>.sumOf(selector: (T) -> Measure<U>): Measure<U> {
    var sum: Measure<U> = zero<U>()
    for (element in this) {
        sum += selector(element)
    }
    return sum
}
```

or more simply:

```
inline fun <T, reified U : Units> Iterable<T>.sumOf(selector: (T) -> Measure<U>): Measure<U> =
    fold(zero<U>()) { acc, value -> acc + selector(value) }
```

If you can accept getting `null` as your return value when the collection is empty, you don't need the zero function at all. You just need:

```
fun <T, U : Units> Iterable<T>.sumOfOrNull(selector: (T) -> Measure<U>): Measure<U>? =
    map(selector).reduceOrNull { a, b -> a + b }
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples. True, extension wasn't necessary. But that doesn't seem to affect anything, the type still doesn't get recognized. `typeOf<U>` prints out as `io.nacular.measured.units.UnitsRatio<U, io.nacular.measured.units.Time>`. There is a `U` (from `Conduit<U : Units>`) instead of `Energy` for example. I think that's why it doesn't get picked up in the `when` statement, but I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: @Altline Your type-checking approach will never work because the `U` in `Conduit<U>` is not, and cannot be, reified. If I were you, I'd just use the `Measure(0.0, this)` solution and move on.

Comment: @Sweeper I need a `Units` instance for that, which I don't have. It's what I need to find out, in fact. The solution might involve passing down classes in some way, but I think I'm going to settle with the `sumOfOrNull` approach.

Comment: @Altline Surely you can just add a parameter to `sumOf`, and do `inputs.sumOf(this.flowRate) { it.flowRate }`? If I understand correctly, `this.flowRate` and `it.flowRate` should have the same type of unit, right?

Comment: @Sweeper That might be doable. For my situation I decided to do it the nullable way, since it's less intuitive to pass extra arguments that are unrelated to the operation. That works well for now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do with `SUnits`, but it's definitely playing a role in breaking your code.

Start by making it `inline fun <reified U : Units> zero(): Measure<U>` and just write `var sum = zero<U>()`.  Delete `SUnits` entirely.  I don't know if there are any *other* problems, but you definitely need to do that.

Comment: You're right, it was unnecessary, but changing it unfortunately doesn't affect the outcome. I still get my exception thrown because the type wasn't recognized in the `when` statement. The value of `typeOf<U>()` is `UnitsRatio<U, Time>`. The actual type of `U` is unknown and that's what I need.